# example to run SSH commands in linux using perl script

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm using Net::SSH::Any to run SSH commands remotely in linux server. But It has problem with linux. From some sites I came to know I can use OpenSSH. Can anyone suggest me suitable CPAN module to use with small code? I want to supply password also through script.

Comment: what does 'it has problem with linux' mean?  what problem?

Comment: Thanks for quick response please see this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986081/ssh-is-not-working-in-linux

Comment: so there you say "it is not running" but you don't say what *does* happen.  show some actual code and tell what you expect to happen and show what does happen.

Comment: I have put complete code in that Question. That is working fine in windows not in linux.

Comment: And the question still remains: What does "not work" mean? As i asked you under that other question: Does it hang? Crash? Just return but do nothing? Any error messages? How do you know it did not work?

Comment: It gives nothing. If I print $ssh->error it will give                           OUT PUT:$ssh="Invalid or bad combination of options ('key_path', 'passphrase') at /srv/data203806/CPAN/localperl/lib/5.18.2/Net/SSH/Any/Backend/Net_OpenSSH.pm line 27"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.60/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm), It loooks like it i an active module:

Comment: I want to capture large amount of data(say 50 lakhs of lines). Is it possible to capture using Net::OpenSSH from command line.

Comment: I would redirect that to to a file then I would use scp to copy the data back.